# How to identify multiple observable return types

Tags: angular

I have a call to an API to get a list of products. However, if there is an error, my api returns a response with a status code and an error message.

product-service.ts:

```
getAllProducts(): Observable<IProduct[] | ApiResponse> {
        return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._GetAllUrl)
            .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(err => this.HandleError(err));
    }
```

api-response.ts:

```
export class ApiResponse {
  StatusCode: number;
  Message: string;
}
```

product.ts:

```
export interface IProduct{
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Category: string;
    Price: number;
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
public GetAllProducts(): Subscription {
    return this._ProductService.getAllProducts().subscribe(
      response => {
        // if response is type of Product

        // else if response is type of ApiResponse
      }
    );
  }
```

How can I determine the interface/class of the response that is returned from the API given that it has the potential to return either the array of Products or an ApiResponse?

Answer (score 2):

Add helper functions:

```
type Response = IProduct[] | ApiResponse;

const isProductsResponse = (response: Response): response is IProduct[] => {
  return Array.isArray(response);
}

const isApiResponse = (response: Response): response is ApiResponse => {
  return !Array.isArray(response);
}
```

In your component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const response$: Observable<Response> = this._ProductService.getAllProducts()

    const apiResponse$ = response$.pipe(filter(isApiResponse));
    const products$ = response$.pipe(filter(isProductsResponse));

    products$.subscribe(// ... handle products)
    apiRespons$.subscribe(// ... handle apiReponse)
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain the `$` in the component? Is that your own syntax or a flavor of Angular? I haven't seen that syntax before.

Comment: It is not syntax. Just just a convention. Any time you have an observable stream, you suffix the variable name with $. It helps you identify which variables are streams, just by looking at the variable names.

Answer (score 1):

There are three functions available to send data to the subscribers of the observable
`complete(): void` The Observer callback to receive a valueless notification of type complete from the Observable.

`error(err: any): void` The Observer callback to receive notifications of type error from the Observable, with an attached Error.

`next(value: T): void` The Observer callback to receive notifications of type next from the Observable, with a value.
During observable execution, there can be infinite calls to the `observer.next()`, however, when `observer.error()` or `observer.complete()` is called, the execution stops and no more data will be delivered to the subscribers.
Modify your method
in case of error or response appropriate block of code will be executed.

```
 public data=[];
    public GetAllProducts(): Subscription {
        return this._ProductService.getAllProducts().subscribe(
          response => {
               this.data=response;//do whatever you want to
                },
        error=>{
                  console.log(error);//or do whatever you want to
              }
        );
      }
```

Comment: What dictates the error? Does the API need to return an HTTP error code? As of now it returns a 200, with an error message attached to the ApiResponse json object.

Comment: `Status code 2xx: implies that  The action is successfully received, understood, and accepted,`why does your api returns 200 for error?

Comment: It is just the default behavior of the return statement. I have had mixed luck with setting the `http header` with status codes. So I resorted to using the default `200` and adding the `ApiResponse` class.